# Printing rows from CSV file in reverse order in php

Tags: php, csv, fopen, fgetcsv

So I've been searching around on google and doing some experimenting with different PHP functions, but so far I have not accomplished what I need. Basically I have a .CSV file which contains a log of dead players and when they died. What I want is for php to read the file starting from the last line of the file and go reverse up to the top. Heres the code I currently have:

```
if (($handle = fopen("deadlog.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td> $data[0] </td><td> $data[1] </td><td> $data[2] </td><td> $data[7]   </td>";
        echo "</tr>";
}
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to keep a variable with the information.  This way you can *prepend* it, instead of using `echo` which *append*s it.

```
$out = '';
if (($handle = fopen("deadlog.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $out = "<tr>".$out;
        $out =  "<td> $data[0] </td><td> $data[1] </td><td> $data[2] </td><td> $data[7]   </td>".$out;
        echo "</tr>";
}
    fclose($handle);
}
echo $out;
```

Comment: wow nice that totally worked perfect. Took me a good few minutes of staring at it to figure out why it worked though :p thanks man much appreciated

Comment: I'm not sure how this compares to ```echo``` with performance and RAM usage.  If anyone knows, please leave a comment.